# Automated insertion of csv files into mysql table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, csv, pymysql

I am trying to insert each row from about 2000 csv files into a mysql table. With the following code, I have inserted only one row from just one file. How can I automate the code so that it inserts all rows for each file? The insertions need to be done just once.

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='s',
                         password='n9',
                         db='si',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO `TrainsS` (`No.`, `Name`,`Zone`,`From`,`Delay`,`ETA`,`Location`,`To`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('03', 'P Exp','SF','HWH', 'none','no arr today','n/a','ND'))


connection.commit()
finally:
connection.close()
```

Comment: why don't you try bulk insert using `load in file` option if its one time activity.

Comment: I tried `BULK INSERT TrainsS FROM '\home\www\T\ins\train2018.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","');` but it is giving an error

Comment: So is it one time activity? if so, you may want to modify your question with additional information and error, someone should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking this code?

To run this you can put all your .csv files in one folder and os.walk(folder_location) that folder to get locations of all the .csv files and then I've opened them one by one and inserted into the required DB (MySQL) here.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import subprocess
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

cwd = os.getcwd()

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                     user='s',
                     password='n9',
                     db='si',
                     charset='utf8mb4',
                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
files_csv = []
for subdir, dir, file in os.walk(cwd):
    files_csv += [ fi for fi in file if fi.endswith(".csv") ]

print(files_csv)

for i in range(len(files_csv)):
    with open(os.path.join(cwd, files_csv[i])) as f:
        lis=[line.split() for line in f]
        for i,x in enumerate(lis):
            #print("line{0} = {1}".format(i,x))
            #HERE x contains the row data and you can access it individualy using x[0], x[1], etc
            #USE YOUR MySQL INSERTION commands here and insert the x row here.
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = "INSERT INTO `TrainsS` (`No.`, `Name`,`Zone`,`From`,`Delay`,`ETA`,`Location`,`To`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s)"
                cursor.execute(sql, (#CONVERTED VALUES FROM x))


connection.commit()
```

Update - 
getting values for (#CONVERTED VALUES FROM X)

```
values = ""
for i in range(len(columns)):
    values = values + x[i] + "," # Here x[i] gives a record data in ith row. Here i'm just appending the all values to be inserted in the sql table.
values = values[:-1] # Removing the last extra comma.
command = "INSERT INTO `TrainsS` (`No.`, `Name`,`Zone`,`From`,`Delay`,`ETA`,`Location`,`To`) VALUES (" + str(values) + ")"
cursor.execute(command)
#Then commit using connection.commit()
```

Comment: I am getting a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` error

Comment: Which line? @python08

Comment: `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 156, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)`
 `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 135, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)`

Comment: Did you change my code to py2.7? Because I posted a py3 code. And there is no Line 156 or Line 135 in my posted code.

Comment: what should I enter in place of the '#converted values from x'?

Comment: converted values from x as in convert strings fields in your table structure to strings while inserting to sql.

Comment: sorry did not understand, totally new to this

Comment: could u please elaborate on the columns variable here: `for i in range(len(columns))`

Answer (score 0):

```
     import psycopg2
     import time
     import csv
     conn = psycopg2.connect(
             host = "localhost",
              database = "postgres",
              user = "postgres",
              password = "postgres"
             )
     cur = conn.cursor()
     start = time.time()
     with open('combined_category_data_100 copy.csv', 'r') as file:
          reader=csv.reader(file)
          ncol = len(next(reader))
          next(reader)
          for row in reader:
                  cur.execute(" insert into data values (%s = (no. of columns 
                   ))", row)

          conn.commit()
          print("data entered successfully")
          end = time.time()
          print(f" time taken is {end - start}")
          cur.close()
```

Comment: the no. of columns you have the no. of times you have to use %s in insert line

Comment: This will read and insert one file. The OPs problem was finding and processing 2000 files.